# Using strtok in C++

Tags: c++, string, io, token

I'm trying to read a file which has input(time and price) as: `12:23:31
67 12:31:23 78 [...]` I created a `struct` which holds values of hour,
minutes and seconds. I used `strtok` to tokenize the individual values
and use `atof` to store them. However, I'm getting an error when I try
to tokenize the time: cannot convert `std::string' to 'char*' for argument 1 to 'char*'`

```
struct time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    double price;
};

int main()
{
    string file, input;
    time* time_array;
    char* tok;

    cout << "Enter a file name to read input: ";
    cin >> file;

    ifstream file_name(file.c_str());

    file_name >> input;
    file_name >> input;

    //while(!file_name.eof())
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        time_array = new time;
        file_name >> input;
        tok = strtok(input, ":"); //ERROR HERE
        while(tok != NULL)
        {
            *time_array.hours = atof(tok[0]);
            *time_array.minutes = atof(tok[1]);
            *time_array.seconds = atof(tok[2]);
        }
        file_name >> input;
        *time_array.prine = atof(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there isn't any implicit conversion from `string` to `char *`. You will need to use the `c_str()` method.

Comment: @0A0D And? Yeah, you can't use `c_str()` directly, you will need to make a copy of the string.

Comment: This is kind of an XY problem, where you've said "I'm trying to use strtok to parse a string in C++" where the question you *should* ask is "how should I parse a string in C++?"  The answer to *that* question will surely **not** be "use strtok".

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Yes, but from your comment that was not clear to future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `strtok` for this job at all<sup>1</sup>. If you want to use C-like tools, then read the data with fscanf:

```
// note there here `file_name` needs to be a FILE * instead of an ifstream.
fscanf(file_name, "%f:%f:%f %f", &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &price);
```

Most people writing C++ would prefer something more typesafe though. One possibility would be to use essentially the same format string to read the data using [Boost.format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/).

Another possibility would be to use stream extractors:

```
char ignore1, ignore2;
file >> hours >> ignore1 >> minutes >> ignore2 >> seconds >> price;
```

As to what this does/how it works: each extractor reads one item from the input stream. the extractors for `float` each read a number. The extractors for `char` each read one character. In this case, we expect to see: `99:99:99 99`, where `9` means "a digit". So, we read a number, a colon, a number, a colon, a number and another number (the extractor skips whitespace automatically). The two colons are read into `char` variables, and can either be ignored, or you can check that they really are colons to verify that the input data was in the correct format.

Here's a complete, compileable demo of that technique:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    float hours, minutes, seconds, price;
    char ignore1, ignore2;

    std::cin >> hours >> ignore1 >> minutes >> ignore2 >> seconds >> price;

    std::cout << "H:" << hours 
              << " M:" << minutes 
              << " S:" << seconds 
              << " P:" << price << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

There are certainly a lot more possibilities, but at least those are a few reasonable ones.

---

1. To be honest, I'm not sure there's *any* job for which I'd use `strtok`, but there are some where I might be at least a little tempted, or wish `strtok` weren't so badly designed so I could use it. In this case, however, I don't even see much reason to use anything similar to `strtok` at all.

Comment: +1:  Here's another way:  `while( getline(input, token, ' ') ) {...}`

Comment: Or stuff everything into a vector and use iterators.

Comment: I looked it up and its a member of istream and I have included iostream, but still the error persists

Comment: `std::cin.ignore(1)` maybe? Or the one in `<tuple>`?

Comment: `ignore` is in `<tuple>` in C++11.  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore).

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, thinking about it, I'm not sure you can use `ignore` as a manipulator. I've edited to just read those characters into `char` variables. That does have a minor benefit: if you want to verify the input, you can check that those were colons.

Comment: @Josh: I've added a short demo that should compile with essentially any C++ compiler from this century...

Comment: Jerry can you just explain what you are doing in that one line, I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` doesn't take a `string` as its argument - it takes a `char*`. Like all functions in the `cstring` header it's a C function that works with C strings - not C++ strings - and should generally not be used in C++.

Use the methods of the string class instead.

Comment: It shouldn't be used in C, either.  It's one of those functions which are present for historical reasons, but which have no acceptably safe use.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot directly use a `std::string` with `strtok`, as `strtok` wants a string it can modify. Even if you use `c_str()` to get a C-style string from a `std::string`, it is still read only.

If you really want to use `strtok`, you need to duplicate the string into a modifiable buffer, for example by:

`char* str = strdup(input.c_str())`;

If you do this, make sure you call `free(str)` at the end of the function, else you will get a memory leak!

Comment: But note that `strdup` is not portable (and trying to define your own function named `strdup` gives undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Your simple case can easily be built using the `string::find` method. However, take a look at [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

`strtok` will not work with std::string.c_str() because it returns `const char*`. `strtok` does not take a `string` as an argument, but rather a `char*`.