# C++ String to int values

Tags: c++, string, time

I have been searching everywhere before asking this, but have not found anything.
There's no mention of it in my Schaums Programming with C++ Book that I'm self learning from either...

Using C++ how can you convert a string eg `"0:03:22" to 3 separate int values of`0, 03`and`22`? Assuming its possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13747129/179910

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like

```
std::string str="0:03:22";
std::istringstream ss(str);
int hours,mins,seconds;
char skip;
if(ss >> hours >> skip >> mins >> skip >> seconds) {
    //success
}
```

Here we are creating a stream, from which we can extract each element.

### reference

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: +1 for simple standard C++ solution (I was too lazy to type it out)

Answer (score 1):

You first parse the string into 3 tokens and then either use a std stringstream or boost lexical_cast to convert the tokens into integers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use boost::split on ':', get the vector of strings and then run boost::lexical_cast over them.  I do believe there's a more modern conversion library that may superceed lexical_cast but you'll have to look for that on your own.  Split is in the string algorithms library.

It will be slower than some alternatives, but unless there's a reason to be super fast, it'll be easy to create and easy to modify so it wins.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/). It also returns the number of values converted:

```
    char* input = "0:03:22";
    int a, b, c;
    if (sscanf(input, "%d:%d:%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
    {
        printf("Three values converted: %u, %u, %u\n", a, b, c);
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to go down the C route, at least use a `const char*`

Comment: The most const way you could go is `const char * const` and while that technically is the type you should use for a constant pointer to constant data, few bother with so many consts.

Comment: @111111, can you tell me why does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Simple formatted extraction should do the trick:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss("0:03:22");

int a, b, c;
char d1, d2;

if (iss >> a >> d1 >> b >> d2 >> c >> std::ws &&
    iss.get() == EOF && d1 == ':' && d2 == ':')
{
    // use a, b, c
}
else
{
    // error!
}
```

Make sure to include the conditional check: You may only read from `a`, `b`, `c` if the input operation succeeded!